# Can someone help with swapping USDT on Uniswap? I've been charged the gas fee in ETH but the swap hasn't occurred

Tags: uniswap, usdt

I'm trying to swap USDT for DUA. I have used uniswap before to swap eth for tokens (through metamask wallet) but on reading this transaction needs an approval and then a swap. I think I've done the approval part and the transaction has gone through, this is the transaction hash:

0xe6ef844fa6baaeb7959eee1c28fc780f9ca7a60e97312bea1a9c44c5bd7d7d50

So now my metamask wallet has been deducted eth but I still have the USDT and 0 DUA. Have I messed this up or can I complete the swap?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided information, it seems like you've initiated the approval transaction for USDT but haven't completed the swap transaction for DUA yet. Let me walk you through the typical process for swapping tokens on Uniswap:

1. **Approval Transaction:**

   - The approval transaction involves allowing the Uniswap contract to spend a specific amount of your USDT. This is necessary because Uniswap will need to transfer USDT on your behalf during the swap.
   - The transaction hash you provided (`0xe6ef844fa6baaeb7959eee1c28fc780f9ca7a60e97312bea1a9c44c5bd7d7d50`) is likely the approval transaction.
2. **Swap Transaction:**

   - After the approval is successful, you need to perform the actual swap transaction. This is where you exchange your USDT for DUA.
   - You should visit the Uniswap interface, connect your wallet, and navigate to the trading page.
3. **Confirm Swap on Uniswap:**

   - On the Uniswap interface, you will need to specify the amount of USDT you want to swap and select the token you want to receive (DUA).
   - After confirming the details, Uniswap will prompt you to confirm the swap. This is where the second transaction occurs.
4. **Confirm Transaction on Wallet:**

   - Your wallet (Metamask, in this case) will show a transaction prompt for the swap. Confirm this transaction on your wallet, and it will be sent to the Ethereum network.
5. **Wait for Confirmation:**

   - After confirming the swap, you'll need to wait for the Ethereum network to process the transaction. Once confirmed, the DUA tokens will be credited to your wallet.

If you've only completed the approval transaction and haven't initiated the swap, you should follow the steps to complete the swap on the Uniswap interface. If you encounter any issues or errors during the process, you may want to check the transaction details on a block explorer (like Etherscan) to see if there are any error messages or additional information.

Please ensure that you are using the correct Uniswap interface and that your wallet is properly connected. If you still face issues, consider reaching out to Uniswap support or community channels for assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I understand this is a 2 part process now, unlike when I've used Etheruem as the token I'm swapping. I can find a page which shows the trend for tokens and at the side the Swap box where you select your trade. I have entered the same value of USDT to swap for DUA and managed to get metamask to link and notify me to sign for the transaction but it is asking for gas fees in ETH still, exactly the same as in the first step, how do I know this will result in DUA being transferred to my wallet? I'm worried I'll just be charged the gas fee without an end result.